Botframework-webchat getting error i is not a function
Trying to implement Botframework-webchat in a react MFE application, but as soon as i try to use any component of "Botframework-webchat" my MFE got killed by error
app-errors.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: i is not a function
at botframework-webchat-api.mjs:1:23790
at chunk-4ZIUY4G5.mjs:1:182
at ./node_modules/botframework-webchat-api/dist/botframework-webchat-api.mjs (botframework-webchat-api.mjs:139:43590)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at ./node_modules/botframework-webchat-component/dist/botframework-webchat-component.mjs (botframework-webchat-component.internal.mjs:3:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at ./node_modules/botframework-webchat/dist/chunk-EZUR2UAI.mjs (botframework-webchat.mjs:3:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)


below is the code i have written
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
import ReactWebChat from 'botframework-webchat';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { request } from 'src/api/request';
import { LoginUser } from 'src/root';
import { wrappedProcessEnv as env } from '../wrapped-process-env';
import { Header } from './header';
import './panel.scss';

interface OwnProps {
loginUser: LoginUser | null;
}

type LoggedIn =
| {
isLoggedIn: false;
}
| {
isLoggedIn: true;
conversationId: string;
userId: string;
expiresAtMilliseconds: number;
};

let lastConversationId: string | null = null;

export const Panel: React.FC<OwnProps> = (props: OwnProps) => {
const access_token = props.loginUser?.access_token;
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState<LoggedIn>({ isLoggedIn: false });
const directLineRef = useRef<DirectLine | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
let cancelled = false;

    if (access_token && !loggedIn.isLoggedIn) {
      request<token>(`API URL`)
        .post({ access_token, prevConversationId: lastConversationId })
        .then((loginInfo) => {
          if (cancelled) {
            return;
          }
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log('resp->', loginInfo);
    
          directLineRef.current = new DirectLine({ token: loginInfo.token });
          console.log("directLineRef",directLineRef)
          lastConversationId = loginInfo.conversationId;
          setLoggedIn({
            isLoggedIn: true,
            conversationId: loginInfo.conversationId,
            userId: loginInfo.userId,
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            expiresAtMilliseconds: (loginInfo.expiresIn + Date.now() / 1000) * 1000,
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log('Error->', err);
        });
    }
    
    return () => {
      cancelled = true;
    };

}, [loggedIn.isLoggedIn, access_token]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      directLineRef ?
        <ReactWebChat
          className="chat"
          directLine={ directLineRef.current }
        />
      :
        <div>Connecting to bot&hellip;</div>
    </div>
  );
};


